# How do I locate the PID code for an ASUS laptop webcam?

Tags: windows, asus-laptop, device-manager, pid

I can't look in the Device Manager for the PID code because the camera has disappeared from the device list. The driver still shows up in programs list, but the camera doesn't work. Where else can I find the PID code?

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't show in Device Manager, even as an unknown device, then it is likely that it isn't functioning properly any more as the OS cannot see it.

If it isn't plain broken, then you could boot from a linux liveCD and do `lsusb` (it is likely to be a USB device despite being physically embedded).

If that doesn't work, then you could search Google for your exact model plus the keyword `linux` as it is often linux oriented sites that maintain PID/VID numbers for devices used in various devices.